# How to enable automatic date and time on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: 19.10, ntp, gnome-control-center

I am trying to turn on Automatic Date & Time but it turns off immediately on its own.

[image]
This seems to happen only after installing the latest updates.

How do I enable Automatic Date & Time?

Comment: Just to make sure, it says "requires internet access". Is your system connected to the internet?

Comment: @pomsky Yes. It is connected. I posted the question and this comment from the same system. :)

Comment: @AksharPatel for instance you can update your time from terminal:
`sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov`
for timezone update:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Comment: @AksharPatel and check if you have ntp enabled:
`sudo apt-get install ntp`

Comment: @kamil, my 19.10 is set to "Automatic", but no `ntp` is installed. So there should be no need.

Comment: @kamil Installed NTP but still facing the same issue.

Comment: @AksharPatel make sure Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services is set to "On."

Comment: @kamil Yeah. It is ON.

Comment: Experiencing same issue, reported bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1858095

Answer (score 5):

### Short answer:

```
$ sudo apt remove ntp
```

And try to enable automatic Time & Date again.

---

### Long answer:

If you try to start the "systemd-timesyncd" service manually with:

```
systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service
```

and check the status with:

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
```

you can see that it says:

```
Condition: start condition failed at <some time>; 1s ago
       └─ ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/ntpd was not met
```

So "ntpd" has to be unavailable in order for this to work. If you check the file "/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/disable-with-time-daemon.conf" you can see some more conditions that prevent the start:

```
 ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/ntpd
 ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/openntpd
 ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/chronyd
 ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService
```

So depending on your installation it will also stop working if "ntp", "openntpd", "chrony" and/or VirtualBox Services are installed.